# libGDX: Outer Glow for image using shader

Tags: java, opengl, opengl-es, libgdx

I am game developer using libGDX framework, but new in `shader` OpenGL. I was trying to do outer glow like this image:

[image]

I found simple tutorials in different sites for example like this [2D Selection Outline Shader in LibGDX](http://www.allpiper.com/2d-selection-outline-shader-in-libgdx/). It works fine but Outline only drew and the image didn't draw I don't know why !

The image:

[image]

In render method:

```
@Override
public void render() {
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    shaderOutline.begin();
    shaderOutline.setUniformf("u_viewportInverse", new Vector2(1f / 99, 1f / 94));
    shaderOutline.setUniformf("u_offset", 2);
    shaderOutline.setUniformf("u_step", Math.min(1f, 99 / 70f));
    shaderOutline.setUniformf("u_color", new Vector3(123/255, 1, 71/255));
    shaderOutline.end();

    batch.setShader(shaderOutline);
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(img, 240, 400);
    batch.end();
    batch.setShader(null);

}
```

Output:

[image]

**Finally**, I need any advice in this field (shading language).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the drawing of the `image` itself as well:

In `render`:

```
batch.setShader(shaderOutline);
batch.begin();
batch.draw(img, 240, 400);
batch.end();
batch.setShader(null);
// Add this:
batch.begin();
batch.draw(img, 240, 400);
batch.end();
```

Comment: Thanks. I saw your post in this topic before :) .. If you can do glow instead of outline, please provide me the code.